# Change default value for Job Activity Monitor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms, sql-server-2014

Is there a way for me to programmatically (some config table, I'm hoping) change the default value in the Auto Refresh setting to 5 seconds instead of 60, and to set the Auto Refresh to ON?

I need a way to make this a permanent setting - hopefully so that it applies to all users of the server.

[image]

Comment: If those controls are greyed out, you probably don't have sufficient permissions.

Comment: @TabAlleman, I have the permissions.  When I check the "Auto Refresh" checkbox, it lets me edit the number of seconds.

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: I need a way to programmatically do this (so that it applies to all users of the server)

Comment: Oh I see, you want to make it the default on the server.  Maybe there's a registry setting.   No idea.  I would ask here:   dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread,you can do like below

```
Open Job activity monitor 
In the left pane you can see "View refresh settings"   
Click on it and you have a check box for "Auto refresh"   
Enable the check box and provide the refresh interval.   
Then click ok.
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d040105c-9d09-46d3-bb37-c69e771190ab/refresh-settings-job-activity-monitor?forum=sqlkjmanageability

Comment: I need a way to programmatically do this (so that it applies to all users of the server).